# PHP - Check if string match the provided mask

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to check if the string match provided mask in that way `&&&&-&&&&` (where & is a random number or character). The mask can be different each time f.e. `&&-&&&`, `&&-&&` or even `&&-&&&-&`. Only numbers and standard letters are allowed (uppercase and lowercase).

Is there an easy way to achieve that? Some kind of regex?

Thanks for any tips.

I know how to achieve that statically but not sure about a dynamic version.

`'/^\d{5}-\d{3}$/'`
this would match first 5 numbers, then '-' and another 3 but like I said its static. What if there is mask like that `&&-&-&&&`?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to _create_ the regular expression from the given pattern?

Comment: Do you mean "How to convert `&&&&-&&&&` to `\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w`"?

Comment: @CBroe if thats possible. I dont know to be honest thats why I asked. If its possible to pass a mask to the function that way `&&&-&&-&` and it checks if the string matches that:  `214s-22-1` -> would give me true, any other pattern would give me false. Only letters and numbers are allowed.

Comment: _"where & is a random number or character"_ - Are there any limits (like letters and numbers), or do you really mean _any_ character?

Comment: @M.Eriksson only numers and normal letters so I guerss it would be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: So use `str_replace` to replace every `&` in your pattern with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (without any quantifier added, this matches exactly _one_ character out of the class) , and add the delimiters and `^`/`$` at the ends ...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76073762/edit) your question to include a proper description and all details/rules/limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_quote` to escape special symbols in your pattern and `str_replace` to convert your string to regex (replace every `&` into `[0-9a-zA-Z]`).

Something like this:

```php
<?php
function validate($pattern, $input) {
  $escaped = preg_quote($pattern);
  $regex = '/^'.str_replace('&','[0-9a-zA-Z]',$escaped).'$/';
  return preg_match($regex, $input);
}

echo validate('&-&', 'asd')."\n";                            // 0
echo validate('&&&-&&&', 'asd-123')."\n";                    // 1
echo validate('&-&', 'a-1')."\n";                            // 1
echo validate('&&&{}[]().+*\\^$', 'asd{}[]().+*\\^$')."\n";  // 1
?>
```

Demo [here](https://3v4l.org/CdltM).

Comment: Exactly this. Thanks!

Comment: one question.. is it possible to check for 2 characters? So for instance I would want to look for & and empty space? Tried something like `'&|\s'` but it does not look like its working

Comment: @pasteam2, notice that `str_replace` in my answer doesn't use regex, it replaces usual string. That's why `&|\s` doesn't work. To replace using regex you'll need something like `$regex = '/^'.preg_replace('/&|\\s/','[0-9a-zA-Z]',$escaped).'$/';`